# How can I insulate an inaccessible rim joist cavity?

Tags: insulation

I am working on insulating the area above my basement walls and under my main floor along the exterior walls. I am able to do this with no problem except the back wall, i have a 2-4 inch gap to get to the area.

It is 35 feet long, about 2 feet tall and 2 feet wide. My first thought was to spray foam it, however that isn’t looking like the cheapest route or even realistic route. I got a feeling there is a better way of doing it and was hoping i could get advice on how to tackle this.

In the picture, I need to get the insulation into that little space above the sheetrock, along the whole wall.

[image]

Comment: "2 feet tall and 2 feet wide"? Do you mean 2" tall and 2" wide? Is there some sort of cavernous space on the hidden side of that final joist?

Comment: assuming an 8" foundation wall then that gap is at least 10.5".  8" + 4" (1/2 drywall + 3.5") -1.5" rim joist.  i hate it when framers do 16" oc and get to the rim joist leave it like this.  best approach is to spray foam the gap but i'd drill access holes into the ijoist every 2' or so.  there should be knock outs.  talk to a spray foam contractor and get all the joist ends done at the same time.

Comment: @Fresh Codemonger, I was thinking to seal that gap with foam paneling and caulk, where blown insulation could then be placed through cut holes. Can you get a reliably good installation with the spray foam through the access holes every 2'?

Comment: Are you talking about the area on the back side of the joist that has the PEX?

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing in there now? Framers often drop fiberglass in what will be inaccessible places, such as wall corners and headers.

Comment: @popham I'd talk to the spray foam contractor to see what they recommend as far as hole spacing to achieve a cavity fill like this.  Nice thing about i-joist is the web is thin and easy to drill in comparison to dimensional.  The rim joist area should have a vapor barrier as well and you get that for free with the closed cell insulation otherwise you are messing with black death and poly for this detail.

Comment: @popham no, I  am guesstimating 2 feet by  2 feet,   the foundation is an ICF foundation and the  walls are  pretty thick.  So really, its a whole nother I joist above that wall.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger  I really would not want to cut holes/access areas  more than what's already been done.  I got a feeling it won't affect the strength as  much as i think, but  there  is already one  there to allow a chase pipe to go vertically up to other  floors.    However, rest of what you    have said seems to be spot on, and I  think  i am going to look m ore into the blown-in insulation suggested  in  the answer below.

Comment: @vandrj63 the i-joists have knock outs you don't have to cut anything.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger interesting - i am not home to look, did a quick google on it - I don't think I have the holes but i'll have to relook later tonight.   Is there anything else I should check for?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q156JNJns4  I'd be surprised if your ijoists don't have knockouts.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger i checked earlier this afternoon, and i do not have knockouts

Comment: @vandrj63 who made your i-joists?  weyerhaeuser?  The knock outs aren't colored like in that video more like perforated.

Comment: @FreshCodeMonger sorry for the pause between responses - looking at them, looks like bluelinx is the maker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding foam could possibly cause damage, pressing on thin plasterboard if trapped between surfaces. Also check it's fire rating. [Consider the following](https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/types-insulation):

- Closed-cell foam sheets that might slide into the gap.
- Blown-in insulation, such as fiberglass or cellulose.

##### Caveats

- The foam panels might not be effective unless held in place, perhaps by adhesive.

- Blown-in insulation can settle, over time, leaving gaps.
- Either can be a fire hazard -- use materials that meet code.

Comment: A) I would imagine that any spray foam sold as house insulation would meet fire resistance and toxicity requirements, though I haven't personally checked any.

Comment: B) I always assumed that blown in insulation would settle, but having just ripped open an exterior wall to remove the insulation after an addition was put on, I can confirm that there was no settling after probably close to 50 years. (I believe it was blown in sometime in the 70s, but that's before I lived in the house, so I'm not certain of the date. It's been a minimum of the 33 years we lived there, and there was no mention at the sale that they'd just done it, so I presume it's been there for quite some time.)

Comment: What plasterboard would it be pressing on? It's going between the rim joist and the exposed joist, not behind the plasterboard.

Comment: I think Blown-in insulation will be the way to go and really what I was expecting when searching for "spray foam insulation".

The closed-cell foam sheets would be good,  however I got zero way  to getting my hands in that area to get something  in place  to hold  the sheets (unless I cut  into  the  joist)